# How do I know if I need to use np.dot() or * operator when implementing a function in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

I would like to implement the following mathematical formulas to calculate a cost function J in numpy:

```
    [1] =(.+)=((1),(2),...,(−1),())

    [2] =−1/ ∑=1(()log(())+(1−())log(1−()))
```

Therefore given:

- w, b, X, Y

I already found a solution, but I do not understand why it works that way:

```
 A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X)+b)
 cost = -(1/m) * np.sum((Y*np.log(A))+(1-Y)*np.log(1-A))
```

**My question is:** How do I know when to use np.dot for Multiplication and when to use * Operator ? For example, why is *w.TX (from formula 1) impelemted by np.dot(w.T,X) and not by w.T**X ?

How do I know to use np.dot() and when to use * Operator when implemening a function in numpy ?

Comment: When dealing with formulas that involve matrices you will almost always be using matrix multiplication, which like `w.T @ X` or `np.dot()`. Using `*` gives you element-wise multiplication. You will probably want to take the time to learn enough linear algebra to understand the difference if you are going down this path.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/array_api.html#type-promotion-differences

Comment: I was writing an answer and it started getting rather long, until finally I realised there is not much useful to be said other than "Please pick up a linear algebra textbook" as there is not much point in trying to understand anything subtle about `np.dot` and `@` and `*` if you don't know what matrix multiplication is.

Comment: Note that the excellent book [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville starts by a chapter on linear algebra, because trying to understand machine learning without some basics in linear algebra is definitely the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

yes its confusing but you should use the np.dot() function when you want to perform matrix multiplication because it follows the standard rules for matrix multiplication and the * operator when you want to perform element-wise multiplication because it multiplies the corresponding elements of two arrays, regardless of their shape.

NOTE:using * operator, it's faster than using np.dot() especially when you have large matrices.

Comment: Why does it matter if `*` is faster if it does something completely different? `+` is probably faster too and equally irrelevant.

Comment: Matrix multiplication can be done with the `@` operator.

Comment: Agreed with @Mark that the note is not necessary relevant but the answer looks right to me